# How can I rate Apple's Podcast.app in the iTunes App Store?

Tags: itunes-store, podcasts.app

This is very odd and I just noticed this for the first time, but it seems, apple is not allowing ratings from customers for its own Postcast.app.

The entire section "Ratings and reviews" is absent for the podcast app:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/podcasts/id525463029

Other apps do have ratings and reviews. Below two screenshots: 1. showing podcasts app without the section in question and 2. showing soundcloud (as example) with the "Ratings and review" section.

I find this disturbing and unsettling. Apple does not allow ratings for it's own software or what? Can someone enlighten me about what's happening here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have been able to gather, it looks like the Podcasts App and the iBooks app are the only apps made by Apple that don't have a ratings button. I am guessing since the Podcasts app (and iBooks) are automatically installed on your iPhone or iPad in iOS 8, and are also installable from the app store on earlier versions of iOS, they most likely just omitted it because you can't delete them in iOS 8. Just like you can't rate Apps like Messages or Phone on your iPhone.

Comment: iBooks also doesn't have a rating option.

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed that. @AlistairMcMillan

Comment: You must be right. But it's still somewhat unlogical. Messages or Phone are not in the iTunes store afaik. Probably the next move might be to remove the Podcasts app from the iTunes store as soon as iOS 9 arrives. I hope Apple makes the app usable soon. It's not working to well, but that's another story.